# Where to find KlamAV download?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, clamav

Where can I find a download of KlamAV (KDE GUI frontend for clamav) that actually works?  I downloaded it from Sourceforge, but when I try to run the file (there's just one file, and I have to use sudo bash or sudo sh to run it) I just get errors.  I don't know enough about bash scripting (or sh scripting for that matter) to try and debug.  Is there an alternative location where I can get KlamAV, like from a PPA or something?

I have ALREADY installed the clamav package. I would like to be able to use a GUI with it. I know there is clamtk for Gtk, but I am using KDE, and I have messed things up in the past by installing Gtk dependencies on a KDE system.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Kubuntu or another variant with KDE installed over it? Which version are you running?

I found [this repository on LaunchPad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/~bigkahuna/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index?field.series_filter=) but I have doubts that this will work on a recent version of Ubuntu because it has not been updated since 2013 and the builds seem to be failing.

I also found [this deb file](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/1589933/+files/klamav_0.46-2~dapper3_amd64.deb) which was designed for Dapper Drake. It also has a low chance of working because Dapper Drake is a very old release but it's worth a try.

Hopefully one of these things works for you!

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I will just switch to Ubuntu anyway even though I HATE Unity! There seems to be more stuff designed for Gtk+ than for KDE.  In any case KDE has too many weird quirks for my liking. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SamuelH: GTK+ applications will run on KDE and Qt applications will run on Unity/GNOME/MATE/Cinnamon/LXDE/Xfce without issues. They may just look a little ugly because the themeing doesn't match or isn't set up properly.

Comment: @David Foerster - Yes, I know that.  But the last time I installed a GTK+ application on a KDE system (thankfully a test VM) it installed loads of dependencies and then things stopped working!

Comment: Then you probably had third-party PPAs enabled that broke package dependencies and Apt didn't know how to resolve them on it's own.